# How do I find the derivative of the $l1$-norm of a vector of complex numbers with respect to the vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to take the derivative complex vector $x^*$ with respect to the vector $x\cdot \sqrt{x^{*}x}$. If anyone can tell me that will be great.

Comment: Do you mean the gradient of $l^1$ norm? Its gradient at $x$ is just the vector of $\pm$, according to the signs of $x_i$.

Comment: Have you tried anything, say, plugging this into the definition of the derivative?

Comment: If this is for something numerical/computational, you may want to consider viewing $x$ as a real vector with twice as many components. Viewing it as complex leads to problems in my experience

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the one norm of a complex vector (the sum of the absolute values of the entries of the vector) is not a differentiable function.  In fact, the absolute value of a scalar complex number z=x+i*y is not
a differentiable function.

To see this, use the Cauchy-Riemann conditions.  Write the absolute value as

abs(z)=abs(x+i*y)=sqrt(x^2+y^2)+i*0

let u(x,y)=sqrt(x^2+y^2) (the real part) and v(x,y)=0 (the imaginary part.)

If the absolute value was differentiable then it would satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann conditions.  In particular, the partial derivative of u with respect to x would have to equal the partial derivative of v with respect to y.  Since this clearly doesn't hold, there's no need to check the other half of the CR conditions, and you can conclude that abs(z) is not differentiable.

Comment: The derivative does exist ae. (when viewed as a map $\mathbb{R}^{2n} \to \mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 1):

If $f_k(x) = |x_k|$, then
${\partial f_k (x) } = \begin{cases}
\{-e_k\}, & x_k < 0 \\
[-e_k,e_k], & x_k = 0 \\
\{e_k\}, & x_k > 0 \end{cases}$.

If $f(x) = \|x\|_1 = \sum_k f_k(x)$, then
$\partial f(x) = \sum \partial f_k(x)$.

The subgradient is a singleton at $x$ **iff** $f$ is differentiable at $x$ 
**iff** $x_k \neq 0$ for all $k$.

Comment: The OP is interested in a vector which is complex rather than real.